# Read laz files are stored on IBM COS

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-functions, ibm-cloud-storage, pdal

I have a problem with reading laz files that are stored at IBM cloud object storage. I have built pywren-ibm library with all requirements that pdal one of them with docker and I then deployed it to IBM cloud function as an action, where the error that appear is "Unable to open stream for 'Colorea.laz" with error 'No such file or directory.' How can I read the files with pdal in IBM cloud function?

Here is some of the code:

```
import pywren_ibm_cloud as pywren
import pdal
import json

def manip_data(bucket, key, data_stream):

        data = data_stream.read()
        cr_json ={
             "pipeline": [
              { 
                  "type": "readers.las",
                  "filename": f"{key}"
              }, 
              {
                  "type":"filters.range",
                  "limits":"Classification[9:9]"
              }

          ]
        }

        pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json.dumps(cr_json, indent=4))
        pipeline.validate()
        pipeline.loglevel = 8
        n_points = pipeline.execute()

bucketname = 'The bucket name'
pw = pywren.ibm_cf_executor(runtime='ammarokran/pywren-pdal:1.0')
pw.map(manip_data, bucketname, chunk_size=None)
print(pw.get_result())
```

The code is running from local pc with jupyter notebook.

Comment: I am confused by your question. Are you asking how to write a Python-based cloud function for that code above? What is the code for the action that you have tried?

Comment: I have .laz files stored on IBM Cloud Object Storage, I am using pywren-ibm-cloud
library: https://github.com/pywren/pywren-ibm-cloud (PyWren over IBM Cloud Functions and IBM Cloud Object Storage) and I build my own PyWren runtime included Pdal library with the instructions in this link https://github.com/pywren/pywren-ibm-cloud/tree/master/runtime, afterwards, I deployed my action over IBM Cloud function to process some laz files with the code above but I got an error  "Unable to open stream for 'Colorea.laz" with error 'No such file or directory."

Comment: What is the code you are using to create the action and how do you create it? All dependencies need to be deployed

Comment: python ./deploy_runtime create ammarokran/pywren-pdal:1.0

and then:
python ./deploy_runtime clone ammarokran/pywren-pdal:1.0

I followed the instructions in this link:  github.com/pywren/pywren-ibm-cloud/tree/master/runtime

Comment: I update the code above to understand what I want to do.

Comment: @data_henrik, Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify some credentials and the correct endpoint for the bucket holding the files you're trying to access.  Not totally sure how that works with a custom runtime, but typically you can just pass a config object in the executor.

```py
import pywren_ibm_cloud as pywren

config = {'pywren' : {'storage_bucket' : 'BUCKET_NAME'},

          'ibm_cf':  {'endpoint': 'HOST', 
                      'namespace': 'NAMESPACE', 
                      'api_key': 'API_KEY'}, 

          'ibm_cos': {'endpoint': 'REGION_ENDPOINT', 
                      'api_key': 'API_KEY'}}

pw = pywren.ibm_cf_executor(config=config)
```